# Anybody had this SCORM "topWindowBeforeUnloadHandler is undefined"

Tags: javascript, scorm, adobe-captivate

I have packaged a simple quiz in Adobe Captivate, but when deployed to the LMS i receive this error "topWindowBeforeUnloadHandler is undefined" - Has anybody come across this before?

Comment: Did you google it? Top answer talks about exactly this (I didn't click into it to read it)

Comment: Yes I did thanks - The question on the forum is unanswered - sure it is a captivate issue - its really buggy generally so not sure if i should find an alternative sooner rather than later

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip maybe just add to a base javascript file or in the HTML directly -

```
function topWindowBeforeUnloadHandler() {
    return false;
}
```

See if that solves the error and then see what functionality you lost.

Comment: Thanks this is a good suggestion - will let you know what happens.

Comment: This type of stuff is normally trying to pickup a unload of the content (like the student closing the browser) in a attempt to quickly store student data, and commit it.  The LMS it self still has to communicate this to the backend which normally has to occur in a synchronous way in order to hold up the browser to attempt to store it.